# Detect Mobile Safari full-screen mode using media queries

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, ios6, media-queries

iOS6 introduced a new full-screen mode for Mobile Safari. It is only available in landscape orientation and hides the browsers top and button bar, as well as the devices status bar.

How is it possible to detect the new mode using media queries? I tried using the *width* media query, but couldn't get it to work.

I was able to differentiate them using JS `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, which returns **208 on default** and **320 on full-screen** mode.

Btw: I'm not talking about starting the app from the home screen, which is a different kind of full-screen mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, height is 320px, orientation is landscape. Here's the media query:

```
@media only screen and (height : 320px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* rules here */
}
```

Comment: I already had a media query that was looking just like this one, however I made the mistake to have it nested within another media query. Anyway, you answer is absolutely right.

Comment: The media query does not seem to trigger unless an orientation occurs, any idea how to make it trigger when the fullscreen mode is enabled or disabled?

Comment: Really annoying. Safari does not call resize when fullscreen is enabled and disabled. With all the iphone 5s around, there needs to be a solution to this. Because of the extra nav elements that hover over the page. Totally wrecks mobile apps unless we can work around it.

Comment: Mmh maybe you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322915/iphone-ios-6-mobile-safari-is-there-a-way-to-detect-in-browser-fullscreen-mod