# iPhone/iOS 6/Mobile Safari: Is there a way to detect "in browser fullscreen" mode? Android compatibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I am wondering how it is possible to detect if a user uses the "fullscreen feature" in Safari. I don't mean if it's started from the springboard, I mean the feature that was added in iOS 6.

Actually, there was a similar question here on SO where this code was posted:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($(this).height() > 300 && 
       (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90)) {
        // Full screen!
    } else {
        // Exit full screen!
    }
});
```

But the problem with it is that it is also triggered when the orientation is changed. Also, I am not sure if it is a good idea to use hardcoded values, especially "300"? Is there a better way to detect  "in browser fullscreen" mode?

Edit: Ok so I just checked: When changing the direction on an iPhone, `onorientationchange` **and** the `resize` event is triggered. Changing Safari to fullscreen also triggers `resize`- so I could hook my function to that event. But how about Android devices, do they also trigger `resize`? Or is it best to simply bind functions to `onorientationchange` **and** `resize`?

Comment: Try out your suggestion and get back to us.

Answer (score 1):

**Cross browser way**

```
$(document,window).on('resize orientationchange webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange',  function(){

});
```

Comment: Strange because it should.